# PHP take all combinations

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I saw this [algorithm that will take numbers or words and find all possible combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256117/algorithm-that-will-take-numbers-or-words-and-find-all-possible-combinations)

And I'm using it, but it does NOT return all "real" combinations.

PHP:

```
<?php
    require_once 'Math/Combinatorics.php';
    $words = array('cat', 'dog', 'fish');
    $combinatorics = new Math_Combinatorics;
    foreach($combinatorics->permutations($words, 2) as $p) {
        echo join(' ', $p), "\n"; 
    }
?>
```

And it returns:

```
cat dog
dog cat
cat fish
fish cat
dog fish
fish dog
```

But these are not all real combinations, all real combinations includes these too:

```
cat cat
dog dog
fish fish
```

And that is what I need, the method to get all real combinations:

```
cat dog
dog cat
cat fish
fish cat
dog fish
fish dog
cat cat
dog dog
fish fish
```

Comment: Why don't you add these combinations yourself? Seems easy enough to loop through your data and add the pairs manually.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as before? You're just having doubts on the answer it seems. why not continue there?

Comment: Math_Combinatorics - "A package that returns all the combinations and permutations, without repitition, of a given set and subset size. Associative arrays are preserved.". The key here is "without repetition".

Comment: If this is just for fun, it wouldn't be hard to write your own function that would add the duplicates. If it isn't just for fun, there is probably a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Have a look at my code... :-)

Comment: thats because you are using a code for permutations not combinations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, here's your code (and btw, thanks for posting such an interesting and challenging problem - at least for me... :-)) - **using recursion** for all possible permutations (by N) given an array of elements)

**Code :**

```
<?php

function permutations($arr,$n)
{
     $res = array();

     foreach ($arr as $w)
     {
           if ($n==1) $res[] = $w;
           else
           {
                 $perms = permutations($arr,$n-1);

                 foreach ($perms as $p)
                 {
                      $res[] = $w." ".$p;
                 } 
           }
     }

     return $res;
}

// Your array
$words = array('cat','dog','fish');

// Get permutation by groups of 3 elements
$pe = permutations($words,3);

// Print it out
print_r($pe);

?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => cat cat cat
    [1] => cat cat dog
    [2] => cat cat fish
    [3] => cat dog cat
    [4] => cat dog dog
    [5] => cat dog fish
    [6] => cat fish cat
    [7] => cat fish dog
    [8] => cat fish fish
    [9] => dog cat cat
    [10] => dog cat dog
    [11] => dog cat fish
    [12] => dog dog cat
    [13] => dog dog dog
    [14] => dog dog fish
    [15] => dog fish cat
    [16] => dog fish dog
    [17] => dog fish fish
    [18] => fish cat cat
    [19] => fish cat dog
    [20] => fish cat fish
    [21] => fish dog cat
    [22] => fish dog dog
    [23] => fish dog fish
    [24] => fish fish cat
    [25] => fish fish dog
    [26] => fish fish fish
)
```

---

**HINT :** By `permutations($words,2)`, you'll be able to get exactly what you wanted...

Comment: I'm trying to convert this to return an array of arrays instead of an array of strings. So each inner array would have $n elements in it. It's proving more difficult than it seems it should be...

Comment: Using the Combinatorics pear class for that now

Comment: Actually the Combinatorics class does help with some things, but it is different from this because it would not produce subsets with duplicate values like this solution does. I still need a version of this that works with arrays instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code gives you permutations, simply add duplicates:

```
foreach($words as $w) {
    echo "$w $w\n";    
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that that is non-generic, and will not work if you are working with more then 2 dimensions: in 3 dimensions he would need to add 
cat cat fish, cat fish cat, fish cat cat. etc... again combinatorics.