# All possible combinations with nested multi arrays

Tags: php, arrays, permutation

I stuck with a algorithm for:

EDIT:fixed array

Input array:

```
$array = array(
  'a',
  'b',
  array('c1', 'c2' ),
  array('d1', 'd2', array('d31','d32'))
);
```

I need to find all possible combinations of an every BOTTOM child in every nested array. 
Following array to be as a result:

```
1) a, b, c1, d1, d31
2) a, b, c1, d1, d32
3) a, b, c1, d2, d31
4) a, b, c1, d2, d32

5) a, b, c2, d1, d31
6) a, b, c2, d1, d32
7) a, b, c2, d2, d31
8) a, b, c2, d2, d32
```

I've investigated tons of similar post on `SO`, unfortunately they all don't work with nested arrays.

[possible array combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853989/php-nested-array-combinations-permutations?rq=1)

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That isn't a valid array.

Comment: why? if syntax, it's just an example

Comment: it's good to leave comment for downvote

Comment: "I've investigated tons of similar post on SO, unfortunately they all don't work with nested arrays" - that's a big fat **lie**. the related section has perfect matches.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: that sentence just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    'a',
    'b',
    array('c1', 'c2'),
    array('d1', 'd2', array('d31','d32'))
);

$new_array = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
```

this new array will give all the elements in the array. You should be more specific when its come to combinations. There are lot of answers about how get permutations or combinations in php in SO. Find what suits for you. Hope this will help.