# Picking Combinations from array of arrays

Tags: php, combinations

I have the following array

```
$values = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', ['P1', 'P2'], ['P1', 'P3'], ['P2', 'P3'], ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']];
```

From this array I want to pick all combinations without a value repeating itself and you can only pick distinct number of items which in this case will be 3.

For example it should be like this

```
$result1 = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'];
$result2 = ['P1', ['P2', 'P3']];
$result3 = ['P2', ['P1', 'P3']];
$result4 = ['P3', ['P1', 'P2']];
$result5 = [['P1', 'P2', 'P3']];
.
.
.
.and so on
```

What I have done until now

1. Looked at many combinations questions like these [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787051/php-take-all-combinations), [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029472/php-possible-combinations-3-arrays-of-2-values?noredirect=1&lq=1).
2. Looked at Chase's Twiddle algorithm [here](https://github.com/fabis94/php-twiddle).

The above approaches seems like they will not work for me. So I started doing my own code like below, but I am a little lost.

```
$values = [['P1'], ['P2'], ['P3'], ['P1', 'P2'], ['P1', 'P3'], ['P2', 'P3'], ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']];
        $result = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $result[$i][] = $value;
            $restArray = array_diff_key($values, array_flip([$key]));
            foreach ($restArray as $v) {
                foreach ($v as $val) {
                    if (!in_array($val, $result[$i])) {
                        $result[$i][] = $v;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            $i++;
        }
```

Comment: I presume `checkAllExists` is your own function as well. So I'd suggest you include it in the question as well.

Comment: @El_Vanja Updated what I have done.

Comment: One thing - at the beginning you show your input array like this: `$values = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'...` and later you show it like this: `$values = [['P1'], ['P2'], ['P3']...`. What is the actual structure of the input array? Are these single elements arrays or strings?