# Regexp MySQL matching word within a set of characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I've been for a while trying to setup a regex in mysql where it finds words from a dictionary table whose letters are in set.

Giving a set of letters i.e. "freedom" I want to get what combination of words i can obtain from such set of letters:

```
The result should be something like:
```

"free", "dom", "fee", "freedom", "red" and so on....

Is it possible using regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given e.g. freedom (and the letters "f","r","e","d","o","m") are you also searching for words with MORE than 7 letters?

Comment: no, the limit would be in such case, 6 letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely NOT possible using regex.

It IS possible, though, using a combination of combinatorics & a really good wordlist.

**In a few words :** what you're trying to do IS both challenging and difficult, but there could be a way...

**What I would do :**

- Find all possible "words" (combinations of letters, up to size N - whatever)
- Check each and every one of those, if it's in your wordlist (Dictionary)
- if it IS, then count it up. If not, go on.

---

- For combinatorics which you may need, have a look at my answer here : [PHP take all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787051/php-take-all-combinations/9787438#9787438) (you'll do it in PHP, right?)
- For a good wordlist, you could start by having a look at here : http://homepage.ntlworld.com/adam.bozon/scrabblelists.htm (I hope it's not too overwhelming)

Comment: Well, lets say i want to find all combinations of words of three letters that contains a subset of these letters "appiuxs". the regex i use is REGEXP '^[appiuxs][appiuxs][appiuxs]', but it doenst work fine. it finds words of any size and i want only three.

Comment: @domoindal if all you want is to MATCH combinations of 3 of whatever leters (e.g. a,p,i,u,x,s), all you have to is : `([apiuxs]+){3}`. Have a look at the demo here : http://regexr.com?30kv5

Comment: @domoindal The `{3}` part in the end means **exactly** what need : MATCH [apiuxs] EXACTLY three times... ;-)

Comment: I used this sentence in MySQL: SELECT * from palabras where palabra REGEXP '([ave]+){3}', and it returns words with more than 3 letters and letters that do not belong the set. It the same problem I've been having....

Comment: @domoindal Oh, that's a different thing. I know found out : Whay don't you try something like `SELECT * FROM palabras WHERE palabra REGEXP '([ave]+){3}' AND LENGTH('palabra') = 3` ?

Comment: checked and now it doesnt return anything. I thing it's not possible in mysql, i think i will have to build in PHP sentences with LIKE. I thought that with Regex i could simplify the query.