# Getting all the combinations of a number in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to get all the possible *combinations* of a given set. For example, given: [1, 4, 7], the resulting combinations should be:

- 111, 114, 117, 141, 144, 147, 171, 174, 177, 411, 414, 417, 441, 444, 447, 471, 474, 477, 711, 714, 717, 741, 744, 747, 771, 774, 777.

I tried using `next_permutation` method, but it isn't what I want (this does not return values like 111, 144, 717, etc).

So is there any way I can do this in C++? Please note that I'm a complete beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are not combinations, more like permutations with repetitions.

Comment: do you know something about recursion?

Comment: For a set of 3 items, that's counting in ternary with the symbols replaced. That's easy enough to generalize.

Comment: I honestly find it hard to imagine that someone could be capable of posing this question coherently and nevertheless not have any idea how to come up with an algorithm to solve this problem. I hope that doesn't sound rude or mean, it's really a sort of compliment. You clearly understand the question -- why doesn't an algorithm follow immediately from that?

Comment: another hint: the size of the set is not known, so you obviously need recursion.

Comment: @Karoly: What you can do with recursion, you can do without.

Comment: @ypercube: sure, it's just not practical.

Comment: @David Nonsense. This problem is trivial only once you’ve actually solved it.

Comment: I know a little about recursion, but it would help if someone of you show me an answer with an example.

Comment: @harold We do _not_ know the number of elements

Comment: @Roshnal so generalize..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a hard look at the numbers: All numbers you listed can also be expressed as the list {11,14,17,41,44,47,71,74,77} prefixed once with 1, once with 4 and once with 7. This points to a generic rule:

> The strings with 3 numbers of the set {1,4,7} are built by taking the strings with 2 numbers of the same set and prepending each element of the set.

Generalize the 3 and 2 in this rule, implement the resulting idea with recursion, and you have an algorithm for your problem.

As a C++ implementation note, make sure that you use strings instead of integers to represent your numbers. This problem is not arithmetic, and tightly coupled to the base-10 representation. Strings will make your life much easier.

Comment: I didn't observe that pattern earlier.. But now I can do something about it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, the problem *is* arithmetic – it’s just counting in base *n* (here, 3) – and, as a consequence, not coupled to the *base 10* representation at all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: With a symbol substitution afterwards, sure. However, I think that it is much easier and productive to think about this problem in terms of alphabets and strings. After all, the OP is trying to produce {1,4,7}^N. The arithmetics are so elementary (only counting, but no addition or higher arithmetics) that they aren't very useful.

Comment: +1 for an answer that gently direct on the right road, without actually showing either the end goal or drowning the OP into the technical details.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with the values e.g. {1, 4, 7}.

Use length(array) for loops, each with length(array) iterations.

In the most inner loop output 100 * array[i] + 10 * array[j] + array[k]

If the maximum length is not known, then you use recursion instead e.g. **pseudo-code**:

```
void Solve(int[] array, int length, int position, int sum)
{
    position++;
    sum *= 10;

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < length; cnt++)
    {
        int tempsum = sum + array[cnt];

        if (position == length)
            output(tempsum);
        else
            Solve(array, length, position, tempsum);
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, no, it's not a fixed set. You assume there are 3 values.

Comment: This clearly extends to any number of values and non-fixed sets.

Comment: I am sure he can study the approach then extend this himself. If not, then perhaps he should quit programming.

Comment: People seem to forget that they are already familiar with the techniques to tackle such problems. It's not trivial for a beginner..

Comment: @KarolyHorvath maybe, depends on the beginner. Edited to generalize approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create a vector of integers (called `vector`) equal in size to the number of elements in your set. Initialize each entry to 0. Then follow this algorithm:

1) Walk `vector`, outputting the corresponding elements. (So if the vector is 0,1,1 and the set is [9,8,7], output 988 -- the zeroth element, the first element, the first element.)

2) Set an integer called `element` to 0.

3) Increment `vector[element]`. Check if `vector[element]` equals the number of elements in the set. If not go to step 1.

4) Set `vector[element]` to zero. Increment `element`. If `element` is less than the number of elements in the set, go to step 3.

5) Stop. You are done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer here : [PHP take all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787051/php-take-all-combinations/9787438#9787438)

**Hint :** It's not C++ code, but you'll get the idea. (I would suggest using recursion)

Answer (score 0):

Well I took the liberty to try to implement the task. I wanted to rust off a bit my algorithm knowledge. It turned out to be like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

vector<int> allowedNumbers;

bool my_next_perm(vector<int>::iterator& begin, vector<int>::iterator& end) {
    for (vector<int>::iterator itr = end - 1; ; --itr)
    {
        if (*itr != allowedNumbers.back())
        {
            *itr = *upper_bound(allowedNumbers.begin(), allowedNumbers.end(), *itr);
            while ((++itr) != end) {
                *itr = allowedNumbers[0];
            }
            return true;
        }
        if (itr == begin)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
void printAllPermutationsWithRepetitions(vector<int>& v)
{
    int n = v.size();
    set<int> allNumbers;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        allNumbers.insert(v[i]);
    }
    for (set<int>::iterator itr = allNumbers.begin(); itr != allNumbers.end(); ++itr) {
        allowedNumbers.push_back(*itr);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i] = allowedNumbers[0];
    }

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i != 0) cout << " ";
            cout << v[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    } while(my_next_perm(v.begin(), v.end()));
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(7);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(3);
    printAllPermutationsWithRepetitions(v);
    return 0;
}
```

The implementation is just slightly suboptimal (because I use `upper_bound`).

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively counting with a base of 3 from 000 to 222, looking up your array of [1, 4, 7] with those digits as indices.  Generalising this to work with arbitrary sized input array:

```
int n = digits.size();
int n_n = std::pow(n, n);
for (int i = 0; i < n_n; ++i)
{
     int x = i;
     for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
     {
          cout << digits[x % n];
          x /= n;
     }
     cout << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the **simplest way** of doing this. You can take **any number** as input from user like 147 and it will print **all permutations** as:
111, 114, 117, 141, 144, 147, 171, 174, 177, 411, 414, 417, 441, 444, 447, 471, 474, 477, 711, 714, 717, 741, 744, 747, 771, 774, 777.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

 bool Search(int A[],int num,int length)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
            if(A[i] == num)
                return 1;
        return 0;
    }


    int main()
    {
        int n;
        cout << "Please Enter a Number\n";
        cin>>n;
        int num = n, k = 1;
        int count = 0;
        while(num>0)
        {
            num/=10;
            count++;
        }
        cout<<"The All Permutations of " <<n<<" are: "<<endl;
        num = n;
        int *A = new int[count];

        for(int i = 0;i<count;i++)
        {
            A[i] =  num%10;
            num/=10;
        }


        int fact = pow(count,count);
        int *Ar = new int[fact];
        int *B = new int[count];
        int value,number = 0;

        for(int i = 0;i<fact;)
        {

            for(int j = 0;j<count;++j)
            {
                value = (rand()%count);

                B[j] = value;
            }

            for(int k= 0;k<count;k++)
                number = number + A[B[k]]*pow(10,k);

            if(Search(Ar,number,fact) == 0)
            {
                cout<<k++<<". "<<number<<endl;
                Ar[i] = number;
                ++i;
            }
            number = 0;

        }

        return 0;
    }
```