# PHP: How to get all possible combinations of 1D array?

Tags: php, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [algorithm that will take numbers or words and find all possible combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256117/algorithm-that-will-take-numbers-or-words-and-find-all-possible-combinations)
>   [Combinations, Dispositions and Permutations in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679605/combinations-dispositions-and-permutations-in-php)

I've read/tried alot of the suggested answers on SO, which none of them solves the problem

```
$array = array('Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma');
```

How to get all possible combinations?

Expected output:

```
array('Alpha',
      'Beta',
      'Gamma',
      'Alpha Beta',
      'Alpha Gamma',
      'Beta Alpha',
      'Beta Gamma',
      'Gamma Alpha',
      'Gamma Beta',
      'Alpha Beta Gamma',
      'Alpha Gamma Beta',
      'Beta Alpha Gamma',
      'Beta Gamma Alpha',
      'Gamma Alpha Beta',
      'Gamma Beta Alpha')
```

Note: The answer I'm looking for should include *all combinations and all different arrangements*. For example: **'Alpha Beta'** and **'Beta Alpha'** are 2 different strings and both should be in the output array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Juhana OP also want's single words

Comment: Can you explode the array, use a foreach along with the total count and cycle through them?

Comment: @Juhana plz don't close the question, other questions could be similar, but not the same

Comment: What exactly didn't work in your attempts? You could start from there.

Comment: @evilReiko The duplicate doesn't have repeated elements.

Comment: @Bono It's rather trivial to loop through from 1 to array length.

Comment: @Juhana true, but the given answers are different than the one I need

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I believe your professor will be happier with this solution:

```
<?php

$array = array('Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Sigma');

function depth_picker($arr, $temp_string, &$collect) {
    if ($temp_string != "") 
        $collect []= $temp_string;

    for ($i=0, $iMax = sizeof($arr); $i < $iMax; $i++) {
        $arrcopy = $arr;
        $elem = array_splice($arrcopy, $i, 1); // removes and returns the i'th element
        if (sizeof($arrcopy) > 0) {
            depth_picker($arrcopy, $temp_string ." " . $elem[0], $collect);
        } else {
            $collect []= $temp_string. " " . $elem[0];
        }   
    }   
}

$collect = array();
depth_picker($array, "", $collect);
print_r($collect);

?>
```

This solves it:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Alpha
    [1] =>  Alpha Beta
    [2] =>  Alpha Beta Gamma
    [3] =>  Alpha Beta Gamma Sigma
    [4] =>  Alpha Beta Sigma
    [5] =>  Alpha Beta Sigma Gamma
    [6] =>  Alpha Gamma
    [7] =>  Alpha Gamma Beta
    [8] =>  Alpha Gamma Beta Sigma
    [9] =>  Alpha Gamma Sigma
    [10] =>  Alpha Gamma Sigma Beta
    [11] =>  Alpha Sigma
    [12] =>  Alpha Sigma Beta
    [13] =>  Alpha Sigma Beta Gamma
    [14] =>  Alpha Sigma Gamma
    [15] =>  Alpha Sigma Gamma Beta
    [16] =>  Beta
    [17] =>  Beta Alpha
    [18] =>  Beta Alpha Gamma
    [19] =>  Beta Alpha Gamma Sigma
    [20] =>  Beta Alpha Sigma
    [21] =>  Beta Alpha Sigma Gamma
    [22] =>  Beta Gamma
    [23] =>  Beta Gamma Alpha
    [24] =>  Beta Gamma Alpha Sigma
    [25] =>  Beta Gamma Sigma
    [26] =>  Beta Gamma Sigma Alpha
    [27] =>  Beta Sigma
    [28] =>  Beta Sigma Alpha
    [29] =>  Beta Sigma Alpha Gamma
    [30] =>  Beta Sigma Gamma
    [31] =>  Beta Sigma Gamma Alpha
    [32] =>  Gamma
    [33] =>  Gamma Alpha
    [34] =>  Gamma Alpha Beta
    [35] =>  Gamma Alpha Beta Sigma
    [36] =>  Gamma Alpha Sigma
    [37] =>  Gamma Alpha Sigma Beta
    [38] =>  Gamma Beta
    [39] =>  Gamma Beta Alpha
    [40] =>  Gamma Beta Alpha Sigma
    [41] =>  Gamma Beta Sigma
    [42] =>  Gamma Beta Sigma Alpha
    [43] =>  Gamma Sigma
    [44] =>  Gamma Sigma Alpha
    [45] =>  Gamma Sigma Alpha Beta
    [46] =>  Gamma Sigma Beta
    [47] =>  Gamma Sigma Beta Alpha
    [48] =>  Sigma
    [49] =>  Sigma Alpha
    [50] =>  Sigma Alpha Beta
    [51] =>  Sigma Alpha Beta Gamma
    [52] =>  Sigma Alpha Gamma
    [53] =>  Sigma Alpha Gamma Beta
    [54] =>  Sigma Beta
    [55] =>  Sigma Beta Alpha
    [56] =>  Sigma Beta Alpha Gamma
    [57] =>  Sigma Beta Gamma
    [58] =>  Sigma Beta Gamma Alpha
    [59] =>  Sigma Gamma
    [60] =>  Sigma Gamma Alpha
    [61] =>  Sigma Gamma Alpha Beta
    [62] =>  Sigma Gamma Beta
    [63] =>  Sigma Gamma Beta Alpha
)
```

Comment: I know that my question sounds like a homework, but it's not! LOL! I know the solution hides within recursion but I'm not good at it at all. Perfect answer, worths a medal!

Comment: Thanks broseph means a lot to me. May I ask what it is used for if not for homework :) ?

Comment: This code is the key to improve my site search engine, so that it can suggest "familiar" keyword for the user

Comment: You could improve your function slightly by making temp_string an optional parameter.

Comment: I got `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes)`->https://3v4l.org/iUCk4

Comment: is there anyway that you could only display a permutation of 2 above only?