# Generate combinations in php

Tags: php, combinations

I've got an array with few words, for example `String A`, `String B`, `String C` (or more)

```
$array = array('A','B','C');
```

How to get all combinations in a new array as follows:

```
$result = array(
                'A,B,C',
                'A,C,B',
                'B,C,A',
                'B,A,C',
                'C,A,B',
                'C,B,A',

                'A,B',                              
                'A,C',
                'B,A',
                'B,C',
                'C,A',
                'C,B',

                'A',
                'B',
                'C'
);
```

Comment: You are asking about PERMUTATIONS, not combinations.  {A, B, C} is the same combination as {C, B, A}, thought they are different permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php

$array = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');

function depth_picker($arr, $temp_string, &$collect) {
    if ($temp_string != "") 
        $collect []= $temp_string;

    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr);$i++) {
        $arrcopy = $arr;
        $elem = array_splice($arrcopy, $i, 1); // removes and returns the i'th element
        if (sizeof($arrcopy) > 0) {
            depth_picker($arrcopy, $temp_string ." " . $elem[0], $collect);
        } else {
            $collect []= $temp_string. " " . $elem[0];
        }   
    }   
}

$collect = array();
depth_picker($array, "", $collect);
print_r($collect);

?>
```

The code is get from stackoverflow:
[StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array)

Comment: Are you sure this works? http://codepad.viper-7.com/KUeisk

Comment: this function receive
A A,
B B,
A A,
C C,
B B,
C C

Comment: Sorry you were right, i edited the code