# Get all combinations of an array

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I'm currently trying to make a function that gets all possible combinations of array values.

I have come up with a non function version but it's limited to 3 values so i'm trying to make a function out of it to become more `Dynamic`

I tried searching SO but could not find a powershell example of what i was trying to do, i could find a PHP version but i'm very limited in my PHP

[PHP: How to get all possible combinations of 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array)

Non-function Script

```
$name = 'First','Middle','Last'

$list = @()

foreach ($c1 in $name) {
    foreach ($c2 in $name) {
        foreach ($c3 in $name) {
            if (($c1 -ne $c2) -and ($c2 -ne $c3) -and ($c3 -ne $c1))
            {
                $list += "$c1 $c2 $c3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the result

```
First Middle Last
First Last Middle
Middle First Last
Middle Last First
Last First Middle
Last Middle First
```

I'm not sure how i would rearrange the values when i'm recursing the function, this is what i have so far:

```
<#
.Synopsis
    Short description
.DESCRIPTION
    Long description
.EXAMPLE
    Example of how to use this cmdlet
.EXAMPLE
    Another example of how to use this cmdlet
#>
function Get-Combinations
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Array,

        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false,
                   Position=1)]
        [string]$Temp,

        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=2)]
        [string[]]$Return
    )

    Begin
    {
        Write-Verbose "Starting Function Get-Combinations with parameters `n`n$($Array | Out-String)`n$temp`n`n$($Return | Out-String)"

        If ($Temp)
        {
            $Return = $Temp
        }

        $newArray = new-object system.collections.arraylist
    }
    Process
    {
        Write-Verbose ($return | Out-String)

        For($i=0; $i -lt $Array.Length; $i++)
        {
            #Write-Verbose $i

            $Array | ForEach-Object {$newArray.Add($_)}
            $newArray.RemoveAt($i)

            Write-Verbose ($newArray | Out-String)

            if ($newArray.Count -le 1)
            {
                Get-Combinations -Array $newArray -Temp $Temp -Return $Return
            }
            else
            {
                $Return = $Temp
            }
        }
        $newArray
    }
    End
    {
        Write-Verbose "Exiting Function Get-Combinations"
    }
}

$combinations = @("First","First2","Middle","Last")

$Combos = Get-Combinations -Array $combinations

$Combos
```

But the output i'm getting is all over the place

```
First2
Last
First2
Last
First
First2
Middle
Last
First
First2
Middle
Last
```

**28/08 Update**

Getting closer but still getting weird output

```
<#
.Synopsis
    Short description
.DESCRIPTION
    Long description
.EXAMPLE
    Example of how to use this cmdlet
.EXAMPLE
    Another example of how to use this cmdlet
#>
function Get-Combinations
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Array,

        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false,
                    Position=1)]
        [string]$Temp,

        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    Position=2)]
        [string[]]$Return
    )

    Begin
    {
        Write-Verbose "Starting Function Get-Combinations with parameters `n`n$($Array | Out-String)`n$temp`n`n$($Return | Out-String)"

        If ($Temp)
        {
            $Return += $Temp
        }

        #$newArray = new-object [System.Collections.ArrayList]
        #$Array | ForEach-Object {$newArray.Add($_) | Out-Null}

        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$newArray = $Array
    }
    Process
    {
        Write-Verbose "return -> $return"

        For($i=0; $i -lt $Array.Length; $i++)
        {
            Write-Verbose "`$i -> $i"

            $element = $newArray[0]
            $newArray.RemoveAt(0)

            Write-Verbose "`$newArray -> $newArray"
            Write-Verbose "Element -> $element"

            if ($newArray.Count -gt 0)
            {
                Get-Combinations -Array $newArray -Temp (($temp + " " +$element).Trim()) -Return $Return
            }
            else
            {
                $Return = $Temp + " " + $element
            }
        }
        $return
    }
    End
    {
        Write-Verbose "Exiting Function Get-Combinations"
    }
}

$combinations = @("First","First2","Middle","Last")

$return = @()

$Combos = Get-Combinations -Array $combinations -Return $return

$Combos
```

**New output** (Yes there is a space before the 'Last' value, no i have no idea why)

```
First First2 Middle Last
First First2 Last
First Middle Last
First Last
First2 Middle Last
First2 Last
Middle Last
 Last
```

Comment: So you want to include 1..$arr.count results? Such as 'First' being valid, as well as 'First, First2' and 'First, First2, Middle' and 'First, First2, Middle, Last' and all combinations there of. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
function Remove ($element, $list)
{
    $newList = @()
    $list | % { if ($_ -ne $element) { $newList += $_} }

    return $newList
}


function Append ($head, $tail)
{
    if ($tail.Count -eq 0)
        { return ,$head }

    $result =  @()

    $tail | %{
        $newList = ,$head
        $_ | %{ $newList += $_ }
        $result += ,$newList
    }

    return $result
}


function Permute ($list)
{
    if ($list.Count -eq 0)
        { return @() }

    $list | %{
        $permutations = Permute (Remove $_ $list)
        return Append $_ $permutations
    }
}

cls

$list = "x", "y", "z", "t", "v"

$permutations = Permute $list


$permutations | %{
    Write-Host ([string]::Join(", ", $_))
}
```

EDIT: the same in one function (Permute). This is cheating a bit, however since I replaced plain functions whith lambdas. You could replace recursive calls with a stack you handle yourself, but that would make the code unecessarily complex ...

```
function Permute ($list)
{
    $global:remove = { 
        param ($element, $list) 

        $newList = @() 
        $list | % { if ($_ -ne $element) { $newList += $_} }  

        return $newList 
    }

    $global:append = {
        param ($head, $tail)

        if ($tail.Count -eq 0)
            { return ,$head }

        $result =  @()

        $tail | %{
            $newList = ,$head
            $_ | %{ $newList += $_ }
            $result += ,$newList
        }

        return $result
    }

    if ($list.Count -eq 0)
        { return @() }

    $list | %{
        $permutations = Permute ($remove.Invoke($_, $list))
        return $append.Invoke($_, $permutations)
    }
}

cls

$list = "x", "y", "z", "t"

$permutations = Permute $list

$permutations | %{
    Write-Host ([string]::Join(", ", $_))
}
```

Comment: There some thinking outside the box. That's a very cool way of doing it, is there a way to condense this into one function?

Comment: See my edit. As I said, this is cheating a bit. But all other alternatives to which I can think of would make the code much more complex.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and scholar, many thanks for the edit. This will give me much to fiddle with to up my knowledge of recursion.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to learn something new and help you out but Im stuck. maybe this will help you get in the right direction but I dont know enough about Powershell recursion to figure this out. I converted the php to powershell and in theory it should work but it doesnt.

```
$array = @('Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Sigma')


function depth_picker([system.collections.arraylist]$arr,$temp_string, $collect)
{
if($temp_string -ne ""){$collect += $temp_string}
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $arr.count;$i++)
    {
    [system.collections.arraylist]$arrCopy = $arr
    $elem = $arrCopy[$i]
    $arrCopy.removeRange($i,1)
    if($arrCopy.count -gt 0){
    depth_picker -arr $arrCopy -temp_string "$temp_string $elem" -collect $collect}
    else{$collect += "$temp_string $elem"}
    }
}
$collect = @()
depth_picker -arr $array -temp_string "" -collect $collect
$collect
```

It seems to work and will get you the first set of possibles:

```
Alpha
Alpha Beta
Alpha Beta Gamma
Alpha Beta Gamma Sigma
```

But for some reason that I cant figure out when it gets back to the previous functions and does $i++ then checks ($i -lt $arr.count) $arr.count it always 0 so it never goes to the next iteration to continue finding the possibilities.

Hopefully someone else can fix what I cant seem to figure out as I dont know enough about recursion.  But it seems that with each level of depth called the previous depth level $arr variable and values is lost.

Comment: Yeah i know what you mean, it's doing my head in lol but i'm slowly getting closer every now and then so i got that going for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with a recursive function. It generates space separated strings but it's quite simple to split each element with $list[$i].split(" "):

```
function Get-Permutations 
{
    param ($array, $cur, $depth, $list)

    $depth ++
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Count; $i++)
    {
        $list += $cur+" "+$array[$i]        

        if ($depth -lt $array.Count)
        {
            $list = Get-Permutations $array ($cur+" "+$array[$i]) $depth $list
        }       
    }

    $list
}    

$array = @("first","second","third","fourth")
$list = @()
$list = Get-Permutations $array "" 0 $list

$list
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by Micky Balladelli almost worked for me. Here is a version that does not duplicate values:

```
Function Get-Permutations 
{
    param ($array_in, $current, $depth, $array_out)
    $depth++
    $array_in = $array_in | select -Unique
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array_in.Count; $i++)
    {
        $array_out += ($current+" "+$array_in[$i]).Trim()
        if ($depth -lt $array_in.Count)
        {
            $array_out = Get-Permutations $array_in ($current+" "+$array_in[$i]) $depth $array_out
        }
        else {}
    }
    if(!($array_out -contains ($array_in -Join " "))) {}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array_out.Count; $i++)
    {
        $array_out[$i] = (($array_out[$i].Split(" ")) | select -Unique) -Join " "
    }
    $array_out | select -Unique
}
```