# Generate every combination of numbers

Tags: c#

I have an array with 100 elements, of which I randomly pick 4 (the same element can't be picked twice). I repeat this process many times, to try and get every possible combination. There must be a more efficiënt way though.

How would I go about creating a loop that just creates every possible combination?

```
double[][] picked = new double[4][];
int[] chosen = new int[4];
Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> exclude = new List<int>();
int z = 0;
while (z < 4)
{
    picked[z] = new double[rows];
    int x = rnd.Next(0, rows);
    if (exclude.Contains(x))
    {
        continue;
    }
    exclude.Add(x);

    // do stuff with the chosen elements

    z++;
}
```

Edit: the question that was linked to as duplicate is different, as it allows for duplicate elements to be chosen.

Found my anwser here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871949/1880554

Comment: There is an existing question on Algo about all permutation/subset of size N. 1 virtual token to the one that find it

Comment: Every possible combination of what? Those randomly picked 4 elements? Those 4 elements against 100 other elements?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried yourself? This kind of feels like we're doing your homework.

Comment: @xdtTransform, here you are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: @Jordec Added code, my "homework" is done, the code works, I'm just trying to make it more efficiënt.

Comment: If by "duplicate element" you mean "different elements that happen to have the same value" (e.g. your input is ABCDA, with the first and last element having the same value) then just remove the duplicates from the input before you generate the combinations.

Comment: By the way, the answer marked as a duplicate does NOT allow duplicate elements to be chosen, since it is producing combinations. If the elements of the input collection have duplicate values, then the output may contain duplicate values but not duplicate elements. As I say above, you can remove duplicate values from the input if they exist.

Comment: @Matthew Watson, TT FF UU is not allowed as explained in my original post, because it would mean picking the same element twice. Also picking TF would exclude FT from being picked later as they are the same thing. I've never talked about values, that's why I specified it being about elements from an array.

So if the array had a length of 4 instead of 100 there would only be a single result (0, 1, 2, 3) in any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say that the same element can't be picked twice, you mean that you can't have , for example, (1 , 2, 3, 2) since "2" already exists? If the order matters of your generated elements, and there CAN"T be repititions, it is called **Permutation without repitition**. *Here is a reference to the theory* : https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html
About your case with the looping, this might help:
[Permutation without repetition C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049495/permutation-without-repetition-c-sharp/34247312#34247312)

Comment: Yes this is what I meant

Comment: The order doesn't matter by the way, so selecting elements (0, 1, 2, 3) is the same as (3, 2, 1, 0) or (1, 2, 0, 3), as it's still the same elements that will get compared. Only things like (1, 2, 3, 2) are disallowed, as it's comparing one of the elements with itself.