# How to make a random names list without repeat in PHP?

Tags: php, list, loops, random

My task is simple - I get a list of names say:

John
Rose
Dave
Jade

and I need to assign each name two other names following these rules:

1. each name cannot repeat more than twice
2. subname != root name
3. root name cannot have equal subnames.

which means:

```
------ this is valid: --------------------------------------- this is not: -------

John - Rose, Dave  -------------------------------  John - Dave, Dave  
Rose - John, Jade    -------------------------------- Rose - Rose, Jade  
Dave - Jade, Rose    ------------------------------- Dave - Jade, John  
Jade - John, Dave   -------------------------------- Jade - John, Dave  

(dave's showing more than twice,
and John got him twice
and Rose got herself)
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours - assigning names for subnames1 and subnames2 is easy but when trying to allocate them to the root name, everything is getting messy.

Here is my latest failure:

```
$arr1 = $arr2 = $names = $arr;
        shuffle($arr1);
        shuffle($arr2);

        foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
            $arr1[$key]['name2'] = $arr2[$key]['name'];
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($arr1 as $name) {
                if (in_array($arr2[$key]['name'], $name)) {
                    $count++;
                }
            }


            while ($arr1[$key]['name2'] == $arr1[$key]['name'] || $count > 2) {
                shuffle($arr2);
                $arr1[$key]['name2'] = $arr2[$key]['name'];
                foreach ($arr1 as $name) {
                    if (in_array($arr2[$key]['name'], $name)) {
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
            $randName = $names[array_rand($names)]['name'];
            while (in_array($randName, $arr1[$key]) || array_key_exists($randName, $arr1)) {
                $randName = $names[array_rand($names)]['name'];
            }
            $arr1[$randName] = $arr1[$key];
            unset($arr1[$key]);
        }
```

Any idea how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10835795/4511585 and ad some condition ;)

Comment: `Please tag your post titles | Don't`

Comment: @PandaCool couldn't extract from that code a random results with no duplicate names... any idea of a good enough condition to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with PHP syntax, so I will try a pseudo-code implementation, hope it is ok for you

```
Input: nameList as string[].
Output: resultList as string[]

def secNames as string[]
    name1 as string
    name2 as string 

// make a list with two copies of all names 
for (i=0;i<length(nameList);i+1)
{ 
  secNames[i]=nameList[i]
  secNames[2*length(nameList)-i-1]=nameList[i]
}
// N.B.: first half of secondary names list is the same 
// as original, the second half is reversed so in your
// example we get: 
// "John","Rose","Dave","Jade","Jade","Dave","Rose","John"


// scan list of primary names 
for (i=0;i<length(nameList);i+1)
{
   resultList[i]=nameList[i]+" - "
   name1=""
   name2=""

   for (j=0;j<length(secNames);j+1) // scan secondary names
   {
     if (name1 <> secNames[j] and 
         name1 ="" and // skip this if found 1st sec.name 
         nameList[i] <> secNames[j]) // never pick main name
          {
            name1=secNames[j] // found first name
            secNames[j]="" // make this choice not  
                           // available on next pass
          }
       if (name2 <> secNames[j] and 
          name2 ="" and // skip this if found 2nd sec.name 
          nameList[i] <> secNames[j] and //never pick main 
          name1 <> secNames[j] // name is not used already 
          {                 
            name2=secNames[j])
            secNames[j]="" // remove choice for next pass
          }
    }
    if (name1="" or name2="")
    {
       //input does not allow for solution
       throw("Problem cannot be solved!!!") 
    }
    //assembly result
    resultList[i]=nameList[i]+name1+","+name2 

}
```

Basically from the list of name we create a second list where all the names are duplicated (but second copy is in reversed order).
We scan that list for first and second choices, and every time we pick a name we remove it from the list of secondary names.
Your example should return:

```
John - Rose,Dave
Rose - John,Jade
Dave - Jade,Rose
Jade - Dave,John
```

Note that this is not really "random" - it will always return the same list when invoked with the same input, but it will also always try to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: umm, maybe I'm translating it wrong to php but i'm just getting this:
john - john, john ,john ,john  
rose - rose , rose, rose, rose 
dave - dave , dave. dave , dave
jade - jade , jade, jade, jade

Comment: Sorry, Eliran - writing pseudocode makes debugging more complicated :( I have corrected this and should be better now...

Comment: the fix works perfectly! too bad a random nature cannot be implied here... though I can randomize the input, therefore create a 'random' result :)

Comment: @EliranShemesh - You could try this maybe: create the secNames list randomly but implement it as a circular list instead of an array and loop over until you have found your two candidates. This should still work as long as you pass an input which is not "degenerate" (i.e. less than 3 names, or something like "John","Rose","Dave","John").

Comment: sounds brilliant. I'll implement this

Comment: @EliranShemesh - If you use a linked list I believe you do not even need to shuffle the secNames list: you can simply initialize the pointer to the list randomly at the first pass and this will provide different (valid) results every time. So given "John","Rose","Dave","Jade","Jade","Dave","Rose","John" if you start the first pass from position 1 you get what I did in my example, if you start from position 3 (the first occurrence of Dave) you should get:
John-Dave/Jade, Rose-Jade/Dave, Dave-Rose/John, Jade-John/Rose

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<?php
        $names = array("John","Rose","Dave","Jade");
        $pickedupOnce = array();
        $pickedupTwice = array();

        for($i=0; $i <count($names); $i++) {
            echo "$names[$i] <br/>";
            // this is rootname
            // now pick two random subnames

            $loop =0;
            do {
                $subOne = array_rand($names,1);
                $loop++;
            } while($subOne === $i || in_array($subOne, $pickedupTwice) && $loop<10 );

            if(in_array($subOne, $pickedupOnce)) {
                array_push($pickedupTwice, $subOne);
            }
            else {
                array_push($pickedupOnce, $subOne);
            }

            $loop = 0;
            do {
                $subTwo = array_rand($names,1);
                $loop++;

            } while($subTwo === $i || $subTwo === $subOne || in_array($subTwo, $pickedupTwice) && $loop<10 );

            if(in_array($subTwo, $pickedupOnce)) {
                array_push($pickedupTwice,$subTwo);
            }
            else {
                array_push($pickedupOnce, $subTwo);
            }

            echo "Group = $names[$i] -- $names[$subOne],$names[$subTwo] <br/>\n";
            echo "Picked Once - ";
            for($j=0; $j<count($pickedupOnce); $j++) {
                echo "$pickedupOnce[$j],";
            }

            echo "<br />Picked Twice - ";
            for($j=0; $j<count($pickedupTwice); $j++) {
                echo "$pickedupTwice[$j],";
            }
            echo "<br/>";
        }



        ?>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: this works fine! - except from time to time (I assume) the while loop becomes infinite... any idea of why and how to fix that? had the same problem in my code - due to lack of options in one of the last iterations..

Comment: edited the answer to take care of infinite loop. it runs max. for 10 times.  So at times does repeat subnames, though rarely.