# how to combine an array

Tags: php

array is like this : `$arr = array("a","b","c","d");`

I want to combine it. The result must have `"abcd"` and not repeat.

Example : $r = array("ab","cd") || array("a","bcd") || array("abcd") || array("ab","c","d")

Now I use the following function:

```
function combination(){  
$str = array("a","b","c","d");  
$result = array();  
$c = count($str);  
$nbin = 1 << $c;  
for($i = 1; $i < $nbin; $i++){  
        $element = "";  
        for($j=0;$j < $c; $j++){  
                if((1 << $j & $i) !=0 ){  
                        $element .= $str[$j];  
                }  
        }  
        array_push($result,$element);  
}  
        return $result;  
}
```

This is the $result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => ab
    [3] => c
    [4] => ac
    [5] => bc
    [6] => abc
    [7] => d
    [8] => ad
    [9] => bd
    [10] => abd
    [11] => cd
    [12] => acd
    [13] => bcd
    [14] => abcd
)
```

How should I do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with java or javascript?

Comment: implement this algorithm by js or java or php

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little uncertain what exactly you are expecting to be returned by your code. Assuming all you want returned is element 14 of your array (ONLY abcd), you can use the PHP function [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). This concatenates all the elements in the array together. i.e.,

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
var_dump(implode($array));
var_dump(implode('-', $array));
```

will return
string 'abcd'
and then
string 'a-b-c-d'

I hope this answers what you were asking.

Comment: thanks,but i want to get some array.  Each array include some element of $result. The array like  array("a","bcd") or array("bc","ad"). duplicate character is  no need. example:  array("a","abc")

Comment: So what you would like is to get all different character combinations that fit into 2 array elements?

Comment: Could your question be solved by this answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely.