# issue with extracting combination of values from multiple nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

trying to iterate over multiple nested arrays to get every single combination of possible values in a new array.

example:

```
[
  ['a1', 'a2'],
  ['b1', 'b2'],
  ['c1', 'c2']
]
```

output:

```
[
   ['a1'],
   ['a2'],
   ['b1'],
   ['b2'],
   ['c1'],
   ['c2'],
   ['a1', 'b1'],
   ['a1', 'b2'],
   ['a1', 'c1'],
   ['a1', 'c2'],
   ['a2', 'b1'],
   ['a2', 'b2'],
   ['a2', 'c1'],
   ['a2', 'c2'],
   ['b1', 'c1'],
   ['b1', 'c2'],
   ['b2', 'c1'],
   ['b2', 'c2']
]
```

any idea how I can achieve this, perhaps I need to split arrays in the first place ?

Comment: Do you want *every* single combination or only combinations with 1 and 2 elements in them?

Comment: I think you should 1. Post any attempts of code that you've written and then ask about a specific problem that you're having, and 2. Explain in a little more detail as to how your input maps to that output

Comment: Just clarifying: so any combinations with 1..N members.

Comment: You have [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array) but i'm not flagging as duplicate because i'm not sure I understand the logic - why does the first 6 elements in the output are valid, but not `['b1', 'a1']`

Comment: I need exactly as above, not all combinations as ['a1', 'b1'] and ['b1', 'a1']

Comment: Can input have nested array? What then - what behaviour do you expect?

Comment: @magos no, the structure will be as simple as above

Comment: I mean you wrote "to iterate over multiple nested arrays", but good to know. How about falsy values (undefined, null, empty strings) potentially occurring in input data? How should the algorithm behave?

Comment: @magos there will be no falsy values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an recursive approach by handing over the next indices and collect the temporary arrays.

```js
function getCombinations(array, max) {

    function iter(i, j, temp) {
        if (array[i] && j >= array[i].length) {
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
        if (!array[i] || temp.length === max) return;
        result.push(temp.concat(array[i][j]));
        iter(i + 1, 0, temp.concat(array[i][j]));
        iter(i, j + 1, temp);
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(0, 0, []);
    return result;
}

var array = [['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2']],
    result = getCombinations(array, 2);

console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create recursive function using two nested `for` loops and one parameter to keep current row iteration count so you can start next for loop from there.

```js
const data = [['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2']]
const res = []

function comb(data, n = 0, prev = []) {
  for (var i = n; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      let el = data[i][j]
      let arr = prev.concat(el);
      if (arr.length <= data[i].length) res.push(arr)
      comb(data, i + 1, arr)
    }
  }
}

comb(data)
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Comment: nice idea with nested loops.

Comment: @Nina Scholz Thank you, not sure if it works correctly in other scenarios with different array lengths.

Comment: i took a limit for max and exit the recursion.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the order too (so single elements first, pairs last), that can be done too, just it is going to be a bit longer than the other solutions:

```js
var org=[['a1', 'a2'],['b1', 'b2'],['c1', 'c2']];

var res=[];

// singles
org.forEach(arr => {
  arr.forEach(elem => {
    res.push([elem]);
  });
});

// pairs
var start=0;
var end=res.length;
org.forEach(arr => {
  start+=arr.length;
  arr.forEach(elem => {
    for(var i=start;i<end;i++)
      res.push([elem,res[i][0]]);
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

`//singles` part is a nested pair of loops, pushing all the elements, and `//pairs` traverses the original array again, just it makes use of the already "flattened" result, `end` simply keeps the number of single elements (as the length of the array will grow) and `start` always jumps to the beginning of the next sub-array (so `'a1','a2'`-like pairs are not generated, as it was required).