# php for loop array length

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have this array:

```
array('Volvo', 'BMW', 'Toyota', 'Kijang');
```

And I want results like this

```
"Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Kijang"
"BMW","Volvo","Toyota","Kijang"
"Toyota","Volvo","BMW","Kijang"
"Kijang","Toyota","Volvo","BMW"
```

and here's my code :

```
$products = array('Volvo', 'BMW', 'Toyota', 'Kijang');

$rows = count($products);  

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {

    echo $products[$i] . '<br>';
}
```

but, unfortunately I missed 3 results :

```
"BMW","Volvo","Toyota","Kijang"
"Toyota","Volvo","BMW","Kijang"
"Kijang","Toyota","Volvo","BMW"
```

how to get that missed combination and perfectly works for different array length?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm not seeing how you determined the "results you want", bearing in mind there are 24 permutations of 4 items.

Comment: Isn't there `4 * 3 * 2 * 1` ways to write four elements?

Comment: what the logic behind this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: How to get all possible combinations of 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array)

Comment: Share your logic . [check this combination also](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c67501e8703e17b668c7b1a371a55d7164e53ae6)

Comment: That code is definitely not going to produce three lines of 4 elements like you said it does. What are you trying to do here?  Why just those 4 lines/permutations? This is not at all clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in this way as well.

```
<?php

   $products = array('Volvo', 'BMW', 'Toyota', 'Kijang');
     for($i=0;$i<count($products);$i++){
        echo implode(", ",$products);  
        echo "<br>";
        array_push($products, array_shift($products));
     }

?>
```

This will give you the following result:

```
Volvo, BMW, Toyota, Kijang
BMW, Toyota, Kijang, Volvo
Toyota, Kijang, Volvo, BMW
Kijang, Volvo, BMW, Toyota
```

You can run the code in [here](http://phpfiddle.org/).Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it in this way

```
<?php

$products = array('Volvo', 'BMW', 'Toyota', 'Kijang');

foreach($products as $product){
    echo "'".$product."', ";
    foreach($products as $otherProduct){
        if($otherProduct == $product){
            // Skip the element
            continue;
        }
        echo "'".$otherProduct."', ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

You need to loop twice to get the result.