# how to convert this php function to jquery function. It returns every possible combination of the values from an array.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I found this PHP code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022215/php-how-do-you-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-values-in-an-array):

```
function everyCombination($array) {
  $arrayCount      = count($array);
  $maxCombinations = pow($arrayCount, $arrayCount);
  $returnArray     = array();
  $conversionArray = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $conversionArray[base_convert($key, 10, $arrayCount)] = $value;
  }
  for ($i = 0; $i < $maxCombinations; $i++) {
    $combination = base_convert($i, 10, $arrayCount);
    $combination = str_pad($combination, $arrayCount, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $returnArray[] = strtr($combination, $conversionArray);
  }
  return $returnArray;
}

print_r(everyCombination(array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')));
```

which is what I need. But I need it to be in jquery so I tried to convert the code to jquery.

This is how I did it.

```
function everyCombination(arr)
{   //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022215/php-how-do-you-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-values-in-an-array
      var arrCount      = arr.length;
      var maxCombinations = Math.pow(arrCount, arrCount);
      var returnArr     = [];
      var conversionArr = [];

    $.each(arr, function( key, value )
    {

        conversionArr[base_convert(key, 10, arrCount)] = value;
    }); 
      for (i = 0; i < maxCombinations; i++)
      {
        var combination = base_convert(i, 10, arrCount);
       //var combination = str_pad(combination, arrCount, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        var combination = str_pad(arrCount,"0",combination,true);
        var returnArr = strtr(combination, conversionArr);
      }
      return returnArr;
}
```

I tried to alert the data returned by everyCombination() function like this:

```
alert(everyCombination(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

but i get only

```
dddd
```

instead of an array composed of;

```
Array ( [0] => aaaa [1] => aaab [2] => aaac [3] => aaad [4] => aaba [5] => aabb [6] => aabc [7] => aabd [8] => aaca [9] => aacb [10] => aacc [11] => aacd [12] => aada [13] => aadb [14] => aadc [15] => aadd [16] => abaa [17] => abab [18] => abac [19] => abad [20] => abba [21] => abbb [22] => abbc [23] => abbd [24] => abca [25] => abcb [26] => abcc [27] => abcd [28] => abda [29] => abdb [30] => abdc [31] => abdd [32] => acaa [33] => acab [34] => acac [35] => acad [36] => acba [37] => acbb [38] => acbc [39] => acbd [40] => acca [41] => accb [42] => accc [43] => accd [44] => acda [45] => acdb [46] => acdc [47] => acdd [48] => adaa [49] => adab [50] => adac [51] => adad [52] => adba [53] => adbb [54] => adbc [55] => adbd [56] => adca [57] => adcb [58] => adcc [59] => adcd [60] => adda [61] => addb [62] => addc [63] => addd [64] => baaa [65] => baab [66] => baac [67] => baad [68] => baba [69] => babb [70] => babc [71] => babd [72] => baca [73] => bacb [74] => bacc [75] => bacd [76] => bada [77] => badb [78] => badc [79] => badd [80] => bbaa [81] => bbab [82] => bbac [83] => bbad [84] => bbba [85] => bbbb [86] => bbbc [87] => bbbd [88] => bbca [89] => bbcb [90] => bbcc [91] => bbcd [92] => bbda [93] => bbdb [94] => bbdc [95] => bbdd [96] => bcaa [97] => bcab [98] => bcac [99] => bcad [100] => bcba [101] => bcbb [102] => bcbc [103] => bcbd [104] => bcca [105] => bccb [106] => bccc [107] => bccd [108] => bcda [109] => bcdb [110] => bcdc [111] => bcdd [112] => bdaa [113] => bdab [114] => bdac [115] => bdad [116] => bdba [117] => bdbb [118] => bdbc [119] => bdbd [120] => bdca [121] => bdcb [122] => bdcc [123] => bdcd [124] => bdda [125] => bddb [126] => bddc [127] => bddd [128] => caaa [129] => caab [130] => caac [131] => caad [132] => caba [133] => cabb [134] => cabc [135] => cabd [136] => caca [137] => cacb [138] => cacc [139] => cacd [140] => cada [141] => cadb [142] => cadc [143] => cadd [144] => cbaa [145] => cbab [146] => cbac [147] => cbad [148] => cbba [149] => cbbb [150] => cbbc [151] => cbbd [152] => cbca [153] => cbcb [154] => cbcc [155] => cbcd [156] => cbda [157] => cbdb [158] => cbdc [159] => cbdd [160] => ccaa [161] => ccab [162] => ccac [163] => ccad [164] => ccba [165] => ccbb [166] => ccbc [167] => ccbd [168] => ccca [169] => cccb [170] => cccc [171] => cccd [172] => ccda [173] => ccdb [174] => ccdc [175] => ccdd [176] => cdaa [177] => cdab [178] => cdac [179] => cdad [180] => cdba [181] => cdbb [182] => cdbc [183] => cdbd [184] => cdca [185] => cdcb [186] => cdcc [187] => cdcd [188] => cdda [189] => cddb [190] => cddc [191] => cddd [192] => daaa [193] => daab [194] => daac [195] => daad [196] => daba [197] => dabb [198] => dabc [199] => dabd [200] => daca [201] => dacb [202] => dacc [203] => dacd [204] => dada [205] => dadb [206] => dadc [207] => dadd [208] => dbaa [209] => dbab [210] => dbac [211] => dbad [212] => dbba [213] => dbbb [214] => dbbc [215] => dbbd [216] => dbca [217] => dbcb [218] => dbcc [219] => dbcd [220] => dbda [221] => dbdb [222] => dbdc [223] => dbdd [224] => dcaa [225] => dcab [226] => dcac [227] => dcad [228] => dcba [229] => dcbb [230] => dcbc [231] => dcbd [232] => dcca [233] => dccb [234] => dccc [235] => dccd [236] => dcda [237] => dcdb [238] => dcdc [239] => dcdd [240] => ddaa [241] => ddab [242] => ddac [243] => ddad [244] => ddba [245] => ddbb [246] => ddbc [247] => ddbd [248] => ddca [249] => ddcb [250] => ddcc [251] => ddcd [252] => ddda [253] => dddb [254] => dddc [255] => dddd )
```

below are some functions from [phpjs](http://phpjs.org/functions/krsort/) that are used by everyCombination();

```
 function base_convert(number, frombase, tobase) {
      //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/base_convert/
      // original by: Philippe Baumann
      // improved by: Rafał Kukawski (http://blog.kukawski.pl)
      //   example 1: base_convert('A37334', 16, 2);
      //   returns 1: '101000110111001100110100'

      return parseInt(number + '', frombase | 0)
        .toString(tobase | 0);
    }


    //str_pad($str,20,".",STR_PAD_LEFT); //in php
    function str_pad(len, pad, str, leftPadded)
    {
        //http://jsperf.com/string-padding-performance
          if (str == undefined) return Array(len - 1).join(pad);
          if (leftPadded) {
            return Array(len + 1 - str.length).join(pad) + str;
          } else {
            return str + Array(len + 1 - str.toString().length).join(pad);
          }
    }


    function strtr(str, from, to)
    {
        //http://phpjs.org/functions/strtr/
      //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/strtr/
      // original by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
      //    input by: uestla
      //    input by: Alan C
      //    input by: Taras Bogach
      //    input by: jpfle
      // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
      // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
      // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
      // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
      //  depends on: krsort
      //  depends on: ini_set
      //   example 1: $trans = {'hello' : 'hi', 'hi' : 'hello'};
      //   example 1: strtr('hi all, I said hello', $trans)
      //   returns 1: 'hello all, I said hi'
      //   example 2: strtr('äaabaåccasdeöoo', 'äåö','aao');
      //   returns 2: 'aaabaaccasdeooo'
      //   example 3: strtr('ääääääää', 'ä', 'a');
      //   returns 3: 'aaaaaaaa'
      //   example 4: strtr('http', 'pthxyz','xyzpth');
      //   returns 4: 'zyyx'
      //   example 5: strtr('zyyx', 'pthxyz','xyzpth');
      //   returns 5: 'http'
      //   example 6: strtr('aa', {'a':1,'aa':2});
      //   returns 6: '2'

      var fr = '',
        i = 0,
        j = 0,
        lenStr = 0,
        lenFrom = 0,
        tmpStrictForIn = false,
        fromTypeStr = '',
        toTypeStr = '',
        istr = '';
      var tmpFrom = [];
      var tmpTo = [];
      var ret = '';
      var match = false;

      // Received replace_pairs?
      // Convert to normal from->to chars
      if (typeof from === 'object') {
        tmpStrictForIn = this.ini_set('phpjs.strictForIn', false); // Not thread-safe; temporarily set to true
        from = this.krsort(from);
        this.ini_set('phpjs.strictForIn', tmpStrictForIn);

        for (fr in from) {
          if (from.hasOwnProperty(fr)) {
            tmpFrom.push(fr);
            tmpTo.push(from[fr]);
          }
        }

        from = tmpFrom;
        to = tmpTo;
      }

      // Walk through subject and replace chars when needed
      lenStr = str.length;
      lenFrom = from.length;
      fromTypeStr = typeof from === 'string';
      toTypeStr = typeof to === 'string';

      for (i = 0; i < lenStr; i++) {
        match = false;
        if (fromTypeStr) {
          istr = str.charAt(i);
          for (j = 0; j < lenFrom; j++) {
            if (istr == from.charAt(j)) {
              match = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        } else {
          for (j = 0; j < lenFrom; j++) {
            if (str.substr(i, from[j].length) == from[j]) {
              match = true;
              // Fast forward
              i = (i + from[j].length) - 1;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (match) {
          ret += toTypeStr ? to.charAt(j) : to[j];
        } else {
          ret += str.charAt(i);
        }
      }

      return ret;
    }


    function ini_set(varname, newvalue) {
      //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/ini_set/
      // original by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
      //        note: This will not set a global_value or access level for the ini item
      //   example 1: ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Hong_Kong');
      //   example 1: ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Chicago');
      //   returns 1: 'Asia/Hong_Kong'

      var oldval = '';
      var self = this;

      try {
        this.php_js = this.php_js || {};
      } catch (e) {
        this.php_js = {};
      }

      this.php_js.ini = this.php_js.ini || {};
      this.php_js.ini[varname] = this.php_js.ini[varname] || {};

      oldval = this.php_js.ini[varname].local_value;

      var _setArr = function(oldval) {
        // Although these are set individually, they are all accumulated
        if (typeof oldval === 'undefined') {
          self.php_js.ini[varname].local_value = [];
        }
        self.php_js.ini[varname].local_value.push(newvalue);
      };

      switch (varname) {
        case 'extension':
          if (typeof this.dl === 'function') {
            // This function is only experimental in php.js
            this.dl(newvalue);
          }
          _setArr(oldval, newvalue);
          break;
        default:
          this.php_js.ini[varname].local_value = newvalue;
          break;
      }

      return oldval;
    }

    function krsort(inputArr, sort_flags) {
      //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/krsort/
      // original by: GeekFG (http://geekfg.blogspot.com)
      // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
      // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
      //        note: The examples are correct, this is a new way
      //        note: This function deviates from PHP in returning a copy of the array instead
      //        note: of acting by reference and returning true; this was necessary because
      //        note: IE does not allow deleting and re-adding of properties without caching
      //        note: of property position; you can set the ini of "phpjs.strictForIn" to true to
      //        note: get the PHP behavior, but use this only if you are in an environment
      //        note: such as Firefox extensions where for-in iteration order is fixed and true
      //        note: property deletion is supported. Note that we intend to implement the PHP
      //        note: behavior by default if IE ever does allow it; only gives shallow copy since
      //        note: is by reference in PHP anyways
      //        note: Since JS objects' keys are always strings, and (the
      //        note: default) SORT_REGULAR flag distinguishes by key type,
      //        note: if the content is a numeric string, we treat the
      //        note: "original type" as numeric.
      //  depends on: i18n_loc_get_default
      //   example 1: data = {d: 'lemon', a: 'orange', b: 'banana', c: 'apple'};
      //   example 1: data = krsort(data);
      //   example 1: $result = data
      //   returns 1: {d: 'lemon', c: 'apple', b: 'banana', a: 'orange'}
      //   example 2: ini_set('phpjs.strictForIn', true);
      //   example 2: data = {2: 'van', 3: 'Zonneveld', 1: 'Kevin'};
      //   example 2: krsort(data);
      //   example 2: $result = data
      //   returns 2: {3: 'Kevin', 2: 'van', 1: 'Zonneveld'}

      var tmp_arr = {},
        keys = [],
        sorter, i, k, that = this,
        strictForIn = false,
        populateArr = {};

      switch (sort_flags) {
        case 'SORT_STRING':
          // compare items as strings
          sorter = function(a, b) {
            return that.strnatcmp(b, a);
          };
          break;
        case 'SORT_LOCALE_STRING':
          // compare items as strings, original by the current locale (set with  i18n_loc_set_default() as of PHP6)
          var loc = this.i18n_loc_get_default();
          sorter = this.php_js.i18nLocales[loc].sorting;
          break;
        case 'SORT_NUMERIC':
          // compare items numerically
          sorter = function(a, b) {
            return (b - a);
          };
          break;
        case 'SORT_REGULAR':
          // compare items normally (don't change types)
        default:
          sorter = function(b, a) {
            var aFloat = parseFloat(a),
              bFloat = parseFloat(b),
              aNumeric = aFloat + '' === a,
              bNumeric = bFloat + '' === b;
            if (aNumeric && bNumeric) {
              return aFloat > bFloat ? 1 : aFloat < bFloat ? -1 : 0;
            } else if (aNumeric && !bNumeric) {
              return 1;
            } else if (!aNumeric && bNumeric) {
              return -1;
            }
            return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
          };
          break;
      }

      // Make a list of key names
      for (k in inputArr) {
        if (inputArr.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
          keys.push(k);
        }
      }
      keys.sort(sorter);

      // BEGIN REDUNDANT
      this.php_js = this.php_js || {};
      this.php_js.ini = this.php_js.ini || {};
      // END REDUNDANT
      strictForIn = this.php_js.ini['phpjs.strictForIn'] && this.php_js.ini['phpjs.strictForIn'].local_value && this.php_js
        .ini['phpjs.strictForIn'].local_value !== 'off';
      populateArr = strictForIn ? inputArr : populateArr;

      // Rebuild array with sorted key names
      for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        k = keys[i];
        tmp_arr[k] = inputArr[k];
        if (strictForIn) {
          delete inputArr[k];
        }
      }
      for (i in tmp_arr) {
        if (tmp_arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          populateArr[i] = tmp_arr[i];
        }
      }

      return strictForIn || populateArr;
    }
```

Where did I go wrong in the converting this function? or if you have any alternatives, that will do to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using a string variable, and the last value is stored. You need to use array variable to achieve your goals.
Try this (the global functions are put inside the global.js file) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282110/jquery-function-which-returns-every-possible-combination-from-array-convert-php</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="global.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        function everyCombination(arr)
        {   //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022215/php-how-do-you-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-values-in-an-array
              var arrCount      = arr.length;
              var maxCombinations = Math.pow(arrCount, arrCount);
              var returnArr     = [];
              var conversionArr = [];

            $.each(arr, function( key, value )
            {

                conversionArr[base_convert(key, 10, arrCount)] = value;
            }); 
            var returnArr = [];
            for (i = 0; i < maxCombinations; i++)
            {
              var combination = base_convert(i, 10, arrCount);
             //var combination = str_pad(combination, arrCount, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
              var combination = str_pad(arrCount,"0",combination,true);
              returnArr.push(strtr(combination, conversionArr));
            }
            return returnArr;
        }
      (function(){
        alert(everyCombination(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
      })();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to declare returnArr as array so it's value is being changed each time the for loop loops.

I fixed it by declaring it as an array and for each loop, i push the value to the array.

```
function everyCombination(arr)
{   //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022215/php-how-do-you-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-values-in-an-array
      var arrCount      = arr.length;
      var maxCombinations = Math.pow(arrCount, arrCount);
      var returnArr     = [];
      var conversionArr = [];
        var returnArr = [];

    $.each(arr, function( key, value )
    {

        conversionArr[base_convert(key, 10, arrCount)] = value;


    }); 
      for (i = 0; i < maxCombinations; i++)
      {
        var combination = base_convert(i, 10, arrCount);
       //var combination = str_pad(combination, arrCount, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        var combination = str_pad(arrCount,"0",combination,true);
         returnArr.push(strtr(combination, conversionArr));
      }
      return returnArr;
}
```

Comment: I was fixing your problem when you provided your own answer. Sorry for the delay, but anyway I'm glad your problem has been solved :)

Comment: @budiantoip Thank you :D