# PHP: View all value of multiple array together

Tags: php, arrays

I want print all value of array together

> Array :

```
$one = array('a','b');
$two = array('z','x');
```

> Result :

```
az
ax
bz
bx
```

But i do not want use `foreach` :

```
foreach($one as $value){
    foreach($two as $valueTwo){
        echo $value.$valueTwo;
    }
}
```

Because my `array` number are unknown

> For sample :

```
array('a','b','c','d','e');
array('z','x','y');
array('1','2','3','4');
array('q','r','s');
array('t','5','j');
array('8','n');
```

Comment: What do you mean your array counts are unknown? You can simply use the `count($array)` function to get the size of your array.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this on your own without using the foreach's then? - And if so, please update your question to include your attempts.

Comment: use array_merge funtion

Comment: I thinks he not tried anythings

Comment: @RaxWeber it means number of array, sorry

Comment: @Epodax i try but not work for me

Comment: @user2007265 Show us what you have tried, even if it didn't work.

Comment: And something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057001/php-multidimensional-array-keys-combinations-combinatorics ?

Comment: use recursion, Luke. In recursion you will find the power!

Comment: @Epodax yes it is

Comment: What you're looking for is called a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). This might help you finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for.

[Finding cartesian product with PHP associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays)

I put your sample here: [**DEMO**](http://phpio.net/s/3wt)