# PHP - Generate all combinations of items in array

Tags: php, combinations

I have a PHP array like this...

```
$myarray = array(
'red', 'yellow', 'green, 'blue'
);
```

Order does not matter to me so I think I am trying to calculate `combinations` rather than `permutations`. I am wanting to get this back...

```
$finalarray = array(
    'Red', 'Green',
    'Red', 'Yellow',
    'Red', 'Blue',
    'Green', 'Yellow',
    'Green', 'Blue',
    'Yellow', 'Blue'
);
```

Is there a built in PHP feature for achieving this or is there a way to do it with loops?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [algorithm that will take numbers or words and find all possible combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256117/algorithm-that-will-take-numbers-or-words-and-find-all-possible-combinations)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays)

Comment: Is the `$finalarray` going tobe really what you have writen, or rather a collection of pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course with permutation libraries, but that you have to `sort` every single subarray alphabetically and remove duplicates with `array_unique()`.

Or you might try to be more cost efficient:

```
$myarray = array(
'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'
);

$result = [];

while ($item = array_pop($myarray)) {
    foreach($myarray as $couple) {
        $result[] = [$item, $couple];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

First thing is you are reducing a source array every step, and every context should have its copy of array. It means, that if you are willing to encapsulate mechanics in recursive function to generate more that two member arrays, you need to prevent their internal copies from being changed by anything else than `array_pop` of their own context.

For the explanation of code above, I'm popping one element off the top of source array, and than iterate over survived element to couple a pair. This way I wont pair "red" with "red", and I wont produce disordered duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

This example below

```
 $myarray = array( 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue' );
 $finalarray = [];
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) {
     for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($myarray); $j++) {
         $finalarray[] = $myarray[$i];
         $finalarray[] = $myarray[$j];
     }
 }
 print_r($finalarray);
```

will print this

```
 Array ( [0] => red [1] => yellow [2] => red [3] => green [4] => red [5] => blue [6] => yellow [7] => green [8] => yellow [9] => blue [10] => green [11] => blue )
```

Comment: This one is duplicating results.

Comment: In question written that the order does not matter to him, so the code prints the result as the owner want. In example also he had a duplicates..
The logic is here for 1, 2, 3, 4 numbers
1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4
As I understand, that's what he wanted.

Comment: He wanted combinations, not permutations. That's why it is not a duplicate question imo.